# When is Aliens: Colonial Marines game set?

Tags: video-games, alien-franchise

I was just playing [Aliens: Colonial Marines](http://www.sega.com/games/aliens%E2%84%A2-colonial-marines) when the question just popped  into my head.

**When is the game set?**

Answer (score 1):

The [AVP Wiki timeline](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Aliens:_Colonial_Marines_(2013_video_game)) places Aliens: Colonial Marines in the year 2179.

> *The game takes place in 2179 and is a sequel to the 1986 film Aliens
>   and takes place after the death of Ellen Ripley in Alien3*

Noting that the in-game profiles show Peter O'Neal as being aged 31 years of age when the game takes place, that puts the events of the game sometime during **January or early February 2179**.

[image]

Comment: @bob - Nice one. Can you please click the "accepted" button to indicate that you've accepted this as the correct answer. Cheers